# C++ / 'string' was not declared in this scope/ error

Tags: c++, string, function, switch-statement

I am making a program that will track golf stats so i need to make players. I made a function called

getPlayer(int playerNum);

and inside of it i have all of this code

```
switch(playerNum)
case 1: return(player1);break;
case 2: return(player2);break;
case 3: return(player3);break;
case 4: return(player4);break;
case 5: return(player5);break;
case 6: return(player6);break;
case 7: return(player7);break;
case 8: return(player8);break;
case 9: return(player9);break;
case 10: return(player10);break;
```

and in my playermanager.h

```
    #ifndef PLAYERMANAGER_H
    #define PLAYERMANAGER_H
    #include <string>

    class playerManager
    {
    public:
        playerManager();
        std::string getPlayer(int playerNum);
    private:
        std::string player1;
        std::string player2;
        std::string player3;
        std::string player4;
        std::string player5;
        std::string player6;
        std::string player7;
        std::string player8;
        std::string player9;
        std::string player10;
    };

    #endif // PLAYERMANAGER_H
```

Now when i run this i get the error

```
    'player1' was not declared in this scope
```

And i also get the error

```
    break statement not within loop or switch
```

and it goes on and on from player 1 to player 10.
I have intelized the the string by calling a file reader function. I am really new to c++ and i am probably doing something just stupidly wrong so if anyone could help please.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This cries out for an array.

Comment: Does your signature for the definition include `playerManager::`?

Comment: i did that but when i run it with the array it gives the same not declared int hsi scope error

Comment: Believe me, you want a container of players, not one each. The second error is because your switch needs `switch{...}`, not `switch ...`. A switch isn't even needed if you use an array though. And putting `break` right after the `return` looks messy in this case imo. It's optional as it returns from the function anyway.

Comment: Post the minimal compilable code the demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaving out the codereview stuff -

did you by any chance implement

```
std::string getPlayer(int playerNum);
```

instead of

```
std::string playerManager::getPlayer(int playerNum);
```

?

Also - the `switch`:

```
switch(playerNum)
{
case 1: return(player1);break;
case 2: return(player2);break;
case 3: return(player3);break;
case 4: return(player4);break;
case 5: return(player5);break;
case 6: return(player6);break;
case 7: return(player7);break;
case 8: return(player8);break;
case 9: return(player9);break;
case 10: return(player10);break;
}
```

That aside - awful code. Imagine I'm your customer and tell you I want 11 players instead of 10. What then?

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> players; std::string playerManager::getPlayer(int playerNum) { return players[playernum]; }`

Comment: "Imagine I'm your customer and tell you I want 11 players instead of 10. What then?" - Increased funding to cover the update expenses!

Comment: @Wug, Might even consider a set, seeing as how a player manager would normally not contain dupes.

Comment: The playerManager::getPlayer worked!! and i changed it to an array instead of the switch and crap. Was that what you suggested i do?

Comment: @user1438702: most people use a capital for first letter in class

Comment: @Wug You mean "most Java programmers", right? It's a style issue, it's not exactly relevant.

Comment: It's been a convention in every language ive ever used.  I see people fight about camel case and underscores and hungarian notation in all instances, but everyone seems to agree that classes get capitalized.

Comment: It's especially relevant in C++ which allows all sorts of flexible overloading of stuff, you wouldn't want a class masquerading as a method.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a few different things, but it might be that you want this:

```
std::string playerManager::getPlayer(int playerNum) //<- here you need the class name
{
    switch(playerNum)
    { 
    //^- and here you don't show  the { and } in your example, and this could be the
    // reason for the "break statement not within loop or switch" error

        case 1: return(player1);break;
        case 2: return(player2);break;
        case 3: return(player3);break;
        case 4: return(player4);break;
        case 5: return(player5);break;
        case 6: return(player6);break;
        case 7: return(player7);break;
        case 8: return(player8);break;
        case 9: return(player9);break;
        case 10: return(player10);break;
    }
}
```

That said, using an array (or vector) might be a better solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have shown the following code in your `getPlayer()` function:

```
switch(playerNum) 
case 1: return(player1);break; 
case 2: return(player2);break; 
case 3: return(player3);break; 
case 4: return(player4);break; 
case 5: return(player5);break; 
case 6: return(player6);break; 
case 7: return(player7);break; 
case 8: return(player8);break; 
case 9: return(player9);break; 
case 10: return(player10);break;
```

This code is not inside a function. I assume you simply have not posted few lines that show which function it is in. Please do this so that we can help you further.

Also, since you are using a list of players, you should consider learning how to use an array or a container from the STL (such as std::vector).

Comment: Even then, don't you think it's weird that there are no braces around that switch?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Yes, but I missed that until I read about it in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a switch for different players, try making a dynamic allocated array for the players, so you can always add, or make a pointer, and then keeping an int in the background to tell how many players are present, or whatever.